# Sharepoint 2010 patch to sort out sync db housekeeping

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, patching

I am wanting to install the patch that sorts out the housekeeping of the sync db, first of all is this the right patch? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2597150. Secondly where would I install this patch would it be on my app server or would it be on my database server or both?
please advice it would be my first time installing a patch?

Answer (score 0):

You always install SharePoint Patches on all SharePoint boxes in the farm. (Where ever SharePoint is installed.) Once the patch is applied, you will need to run PSConfig (either the wizard or from PowerShell) to complete the process on every server in the farm. Bear in mind that you will suffer an outage when the Config Wizard runs on the machine to update the farm databases.

You will know you have it right when you look at "Servers in Farm" and see a status of "No action required" and the version number for the farm matches your patch level.

It should also be obvious that you never apply a patch in production before testing it in a Test environment.